# Firebase getValue() returns null on a existing object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app to store data onto my Firebase Database. I want to get the data from the database and make it into a custom listview.

Every data in my database is labeled by numbers and I am making a way to delete the data, but still maintain the number sequence. For example, when I have data `1`, `2`, and `3`, and I deleted number `2`, I remove number the number `2` and number `3` first and I transfer the data from number `3` to form a new number `2` with the data that is once stored in number `3`.

After doing that, I call `addValueEventListener` to get the new data and the app crashes with null pointer exception. I know its kind of hard to read my question but please help. Thanks!

Here is my Value Event Listener (`apmodule` is the data that I want to upload):

```
final ValueEventListener VEL=new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            apModuleArrayList.clear();
            APModule apModule;
            String name,account,password;
            boolean vip;
            childrenCount=dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            for (int i=0;i<childrenCount;i++){
                name=dataSnapshot.child(Integer.toString(i+1)).child("name:").getValue().toString();
                account=dataSnapshot.child(Integer.toString(i+1)).child("account:").getValue().toString();
                password=dataSnapshot.child(Integer.toString(i+1)).child("password:").getValue().toString();
                vip=(boolean)dataSnapshot.child(Integer.toString(i+1)).child("VIP:").getValue();
                apModule=new APModule(Uid,name,account,password,vip);
                apModuleArrayList.add(apModule);
            }
            refresh();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

Here is my delete part inside an alert dialog (the rearrange method is for deleting the data on Firebase and re-arrange the number index):

```
.setNegativeButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").removeEventListener(VEL);
                            reArrange(position+1);
                            for (int i=0;i<200000000;i++);
                            for (int i=0;i<200000000;i++);
                            for (int i=0;i<200000000;i++);
                            for (int i=0;i<200000000;i++);
                            databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").addValueEventListener(VEL);
                        }
                    })
```

The rearrange method:

```
public void reArrange(final int removed) {
    remove(removed);
    databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<APModule> arrayList = new ArrayList<APModule>();
            long child = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()+1;
            arrayList.clear();
            for (int i = removed; child > i; i++) {
                String n, a, p;
                boolean v;
                n = (String) dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(i + 1)).child("name:").getValue();
                a = (String) dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(i + 1)).child("account:").getValue();
                p = (String) dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(i + 1)).child("password:").getValue();
                v = (boolean) dataSnapshot.child(String.valueOf(i + 1)).child("VIP:").getValue();
                APModule module = new APModule(Uid, n, a, p, v);
                arrayList.add(module);
            }
            for (int i = removed; child> i; i++){
                remove((int) i+1);
            }
            for (int i=0;i<200000000;i++);
            for(int i=0;(child-removed)>i;i++){
                APModule apModule=arrayList.get(i);
                databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").child(Long.toString(i+removed)).child("name:").setValue(apModule.getname());
                databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").child(Long.toString(i+removed)).child("account:").setValue(apModule.getAccount());
                databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").child(Long.toString(i+removed)).child("password:").setValue(apModule.getpassword());
                databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").child(Long.toString(i+removed)).child("VIP:").setValue(apModule.getVip());
            }
            for (int i=0;i<200000000;i++);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

The remove method I mentioned in the rearrange method:

```
public void remove(int delete){
    databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").child(String.valueOf(delete)).child("name:").removeValue();
    databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").child(String.valueOf(delete)).child("account:").removeValue();
    databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").child(String.valueOf(delete)).child("password:").removeValue();
    databaseReference.child("users").child("UserID").child(Uid).child("data").child(String.valueOf(delete)).child("VIP:").removeValue();
}
```

And here is my log cat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: earth.planet.passwordguard, PID: 32506
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                  at earth.planet.passwordguard.Fragment1$1.onDataChange(Fragment1.java:74)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajp.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakp.zzcxi(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaks$1.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

The null pointer exception is thrown in the VEL, but the strange thing I don't understand is that after the app crashes and I restart the app, then refresh the listview with the SAME VEL, the app didn't crash and show the data perfectly fine.

Comment: Why do you have loops that go up to a very high hard-coded value? Why are you calling them so often?

Comment: You're apparently getting no valid object here `onDataChange(Fragment1.java:74)`. We have no way of knowing what line that is.

Comment: The high hard coded loop is for a gap between uploading and downloading data, if I take it out it will failed writing the data

Comment: Fragment 1.java:74 is in the VEL, the line getting the "name" data